# Want to display some information in text view in a specific order or arrangement when the button is pressed

Tags: android, eclipse

I am fairly new to android programming. My questions is that how to display some information in text view in a specific order or arrangement when the button (NEXT BUTTON) is pressed and the information is repeated in the same order when the other button (BACK BUTTON) is pressed.

By far now I have only be succeeded in generating random numbers through an array.
My code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String[] answers = {

                "info 1", "info 2", "info 3", "info 4", "info 5"

                };

                String answer = "";

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(answers.length);
                answer = Integer.toString(randomNumber);

                answer = answers[randomNumber];
                answerLabel.setText(answer);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ArrayList (because ArrayList is an ordered structure) to put your information. 
Then, when you pressed (on click button) iterate the List and concat the values in a text view.

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
//Add elements to ArrayList object
aList.add("1");
aList.add("2");
aList.add("3");
aList.add("4");
aList.add("5");
```

When you pressed back button (on click for back button) make

```
Collections.reverse(aList);
```

and iterate and concat values in your text view field in reverse order.

To iterate the list make:

```
String stringResult = "";

for (String str : aList) {
    stringResult += str + "\t";
}
```

To put the result in the label:

```
answerLabel.setText(stringResult );
```

Comment: You try it? it results?

Comment: bro tried but cant really seem to apply it correctly, maybe i am making some mistakes in applying the methods you wrote.

Comment: what is your problem now?